# error login gmail selenium con python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

tengo un error con el siguiente codigo, segun el ide funciona correctamente y arroja "login exitoso"

por otro lador el navegador

1. abre gmail
2. ingresa usuario
3. hace click al xpath siguiente
4. Ingresa contraseña
5. hace click al xpath contraseña pero no sucede nada

si borro el punto 3, el programa si ejecuta correctamente el punto 5 del lado del navegado

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver import WebDriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time, unittest

def is_alert_present(wd):
    try:
        wd.switch_to_alert().text
        return True
    except:
        return False

class (unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.wd = WebDriver()
        self.wd.implicitly_wait(60)

    def test_(self):
        success = True
        wd = self.wd
        wd.get("https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=mail&passive=true&rm=false&continue=https://mail.google.com/mail/&ss=1&scc=1&ltmpl=default&ltmplcache=2&emr=1&osid=1#")

        wd.find_element_by_id("identifierId").send_keys("usuario")
        wd.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='identifierNext']//span[.='Siguiente']").click()
        time.sleep(10)
        wd.find_element_by_name("password").send_keys("pass")
        wd.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='passwordNext']//span[.='Siguiente']").click()
        print("login exitoso")
        self.assertTrue(success)

    def tearDown(self):
        self.wd.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Tal vez cambiando el XPath por este `.//*[@id='identifierNext']//span` ya que de esta forma no depende del idioma del navegador, donde puedes encontrarte con el texto del boton en inglés, por ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: hice el debug del programa y se ejecutan todas las sentencias correctamente. no se ejecuta correctamente  el punto 5.

Comment: Has probado a hacer lo mismo que te sugiero en mi respuesta, que el span sea genrico?

Comment: Utilizando los XPath de los botones siguientes sin el texto 'Siguiente' me ha funcionado perfectamente: `.//div[@id='identifierNext']//span` y en el segundo boton: `.//div[@id='passwordNext']//span`